# Mysql Stored Procedure isn't there?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have this Stored Procedure. When I execute it in my PhpMyAdmin on Wamp, it says it executed and everything. When I try to use it in a query, it says the function is not there. What am I doing wrong?

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `sql_level`(IN exp INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT id
    FROM `levels`
    WHERE experience <= exp DESC LIMIT 1;
      id = id-1;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is the Query I'm trying to run.

```
$id = 1;
if($stmt->prepare("SELECT sql_level(attack) FROM `users` WHERE id = ?")) { 
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->bind_result($attack); 
$stmt->fetch(); echo "<h1 align='center'>".$attack."</h1>";  } 
else { die($stmt->error); }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if the SP is available to the user account you're using it from your app? phpmyadmin generally has a superuser-level account to access mysql, and your app most likely doesn't.

Comment: When I try to use it in a query, it says the function is not there.:- Can you provide your query here?

Comment: Editted. Also, I am the top user. It's run on my local environment.

Comment: I think MySQL doesn't support stored procedure call within SQL queries. Please refer following link: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,28061,30479#msg-30479

Comment: Then how do i go about solving this problem?

Comment: Covert your stored procedure to function and make sure you return id from your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION `sql_level`(exp INT)
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE ReturnId INT;

SELECT id-1 INTO ReturnId
FROM `levels`
WHERE experience <= exp;

RETURN ReturnId;
END;
```

This is what I ended up using to make it work. Thanks! Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You want to create your routine as a [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-function.html) instead of a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION `sql_level`(exp INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE ReturnId INT;

    SELECT id-1 INTO ReturnId
    FROM `levels`
    WHERE experience <= exp DESC LIMIT 1;

    RETURN ReturnId;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I get an error.                                                       #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC LIMIT 1; id = id-1; RETURN id; END' at line 6

Comment: @AlanPHP: Sorry for the delay. Edited the answer.